# Can you turn off Peek Definition in Visual Studio 2013 and up?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, productivity-power-tools

In Visual Studio 2013 and up, there is the **Peek Definition** feature when you Ctrl + Click. At first I thought this was cool, but I have found that the majority of the time, I need to click the `Promote to Document` button, since I make lots of changes to the files I Ctrl + Click on. But after Googling how to turn off Peek Definition, I can't find any details on if this is possible. What I would really like is for the Ctrl + Click functionality to go back to opening the definition in its own tab, like in previous versions of VS. Is this possible?

Comment: I *despise* this "feature": it frequently pops up unexpectedly when I'm using the mouse to click on a word that I want to replace, and my left hand is readying to Control-V for pasting. I frequently end up renaming a class because my hands are faster than my vision. But I can't find any way to disable it.

Comment: @sfuqua I had the same issue, but even before - In my case it was due to a double assignment of the Ctrl+Click command. Both Resharper and the Power-Tools provide this feature and assigned it. So disabling the Powertools one solved the problem for me.

Comment: most annoying when the definition is in the same file.. you get the definition often just a few lines from original

Comment: @sfuqua it's even worse when you accidentally do the same into a header only library and end up getting thousands of lines of errors that just look like jibberish.

Answer (score 223, accepted):

In pre 2017 Visual Studio:

<kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Options</kbd>→<kbd>Productivity Power Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Other Extensions</kbd>→<kbd>Control click shows definitions in Peek</kbd>

Adam Garner pointed out that in Visual Studio 2017, the location is:

<kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Options</kbd>→<kbd>Text Editor</kbd>→<kbd>General</kbd>→<kbd>Enable mouse click to perform Go to Definition</kbd>

Comment: I looked through all the settings and never saw this. This restores Ctrl + Click functionality to opening the full document instead of peeking. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Really crappy function that seems to only work on my home pc and fail on my work PC.

Comment: Praise be! foisting that Peek feature on us was just cruel

Comment: Haha, it's amazing that such a small feature turns into big deal when you can't figure out how to turn it off. I know since I spent some time time trying to disable it, too.

Comment: Adding a comment here for people who might be searching for Ctrl+Click with Resharper. I thought it was a Resharper setting, and had been searching for how to turn it off (I didn't know what the feature was called, I had to search for "Promote to Document" and reverse lookup that way). Thanks.

Comment: FYI, if you want to disable Ctrl+Click all together it's under Tools -> Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> Turn Extensions On/Off -> Ctrl+Click Go To Definition -- and you can just turn it off, but it requires a Visual Studio restart.

Comment: With JetBrains ReSharper installed, the Control click shows definitions in Peek option was not available.

Comment: I had disabled Ctrl+Click in Productivity Power Tools and wasn't able to see this option. In this case, to see the option, you must first enable Ctrl+Click and then restart Visual Studio to see the option.

Comment: God I hate PPT. Custom Document Well is the only good thing in that addon.

Comment: It's moved in VS 2017. Check out @AdamGarner's answer below

Comment: Please also note that you need to check the setting under Productivity Power Tools as well (yes, in VS 2017). The setting is called `Control click shows definitions in Peek`. This setting exists in 2-3 different places, and any of them could cause the issue.

Answer (score 17):

If you have Resharper AND Productivity Power Tools, by default this will cause `ctrl + click` to go to definition AND peek the definition. Very annoying. The solution from @SnowFatal will turn off the peek functionality. Resharper's option is listed as "Go to Declaration on <Control + Left Click> in the editor".

Answer (score 10):

In the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 (15.4.0) it is:

<kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Options</kbd>→<kbd>Text Editor</kbd>→<kbd>General</kbd>→<kbd>Enable mouse click to perform Go to Definition</kbd>

You can either disable it by unchecking the box, or set a different key to trigger the mode.

Comment: No more unpredictable behaviour when using R# with VS'17! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Ctrl + Click -> Peek Definition is actually enabled by Productivity Power Tools. If you disable "Ctrl + Click Go To Definition" in Productivity Power Tools options then this behaviour will disappear.

Comment: That removes the Ctrl + Click functionality entirely. I want to keep the Ctrl + Click functionality, but have it open up the document instead of opening the Peek Definition. This is what I haven't figured out how to do yet. I'm thinking it must not be possible in VS2013.

Comment: F12 (plain old "go to definition") will open the definition in a new window - would that help? Same number of keystrokes, different order (click on the symbol, then press F12).

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for -- didn't realize it was here, but the one above pointed me in the right direction -- wish I'd seen it first.  I'm with you @MarkWilson-ThomasMSFT I would much rather push F12 to go to definition, then randomly be editing some other file because I was clicking and copying or clicking and pasting... (Ctrl + C, or Ctrl + V).

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2017 it is:

<kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Options</kbd>→<kbd>Productivity Power Tools</kbd>→<kbd>General</kbd>→<kbd>Control click shows definitions in Peek</kbd>

Comment: For some reason, after disabling this option in VS2017, it still does not work.

Comment: In 2017 to disable ctrl+click completely tou need to go to Tools->Exstensions and Updates and disable the control click go to definition extension