# Visual Studio 2015: Disable Control+Click Navigation

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2015

After upgrading to Visual Studio 2015, holding control while clicking on a symbol navigates to that symbol definition.  In prior versions, this would instead select the entire word.

How can I disable the navigation event when <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + Click(ing) a symbol, so that it highlights the word?

I do have Resharper (Ultimate 9.2) installed.  The configuration option under `Environment -> Search & Navigation -> Go to Declaration on Control + Click in the editor` is not checked.

All the search engine results make mention of this being a feature of the Productivity Power Tools extensions in previous versions of Visual Studio.  I do not have that extension installed.

Comment: Could you try to disable option `Text Editor` > `All languages` > (your language) > `Enable single-click URL navigation`?

Comment: That had no effect. :(

Comment: In Visual Studio options and in Resharper options, try searching for "click". Maybe you have some others options there I cannot see in my VS Professional.

Comment: Do you have the Productivity Power Tools extension installed? It also offers this feature (and an option to disable it).

Comment: The answer I am looking for is here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433905/can-you-turn-off-peek-definition-in-visual-studio-2013

Comment: @MattMurrell any news about this?

Comment: Control+Click Navigation is not default in VS 2015. I would love to have it but it doesn't exist. To select a whole word I use double click. This works in every text editor I have ever seen. Even Microsoft's Notepad.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I found my solution in the "Options - Text Editor - General" settings. This was on VS 2017 thou.

[image]

Comment: **This** resolved it for me. I wanted the ReSharper behavior but something used ctrl+leftclick too so I always jumped somewhere in the middle of the document. Did not find it in the Productivity Power Tools, cause I have deinstalled this extension part. Nice to see that Visual Studio includes this functionality by default now, but it was hell to find the option. It just randomly activated it in the last update I guess.

Comment: That was tricky, After updating VS, the options are reset for some reason

Comment: This solution still works in VS2019.  Thank you.  I was going crazy trying to turn that off.

Comment: If only the Search filter could find this option when I write "ctrl".

Comment: How can this be the accepted answer? VS2017 is not VS2015. This setting doesn't exist in VS2015.

Answer (score 17):

To disable navigation to symbol definitions in VS2015,
this one worked for me.

[image]

Comment: That option is part of the Productivity Power tools extenstion which I do not have installed.

Answer (score 9):

With Resharper Ultimate 2016.3.1, I could fix the issue by disabling "Rich mouse navigation in the editor". It can be found in Resharper Options window, under Environment > Search & Navigation.
Maybe updating Resharper could solve the issue.

Also, Productivity Power Tools is not installed on my machine.

Comment: Perfect, this should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

In vs 2017 this setting is available in `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General -> Enable mouse click to perform Go to Definition`.

You can uncheck it!

Answer (score 2):

Go to ReSharper Options > Environment > Search & Navigation, then uncheck the following options:

- Rich mouse navigation in the editor
- Enable 'Smart go to declaration'

I finally solved it following the info I found on this [page](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206651485-Disable-Ctrl-Click-Navigate)..

Answer (score 1):

**edit**

Ensure you are using Visual Studio as your resharper keyboard scheme.

Environment -> Keyboard & Menus

[image]

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard

To stop the go to declaration, select it and input a new key short cut for it. In this image I have demonstrated that I changed this short cut to ctr num 1 and could not change it to ctr num 3. On testing crt click does not no take me to the declaration.

[image]

Find the shortcut you want to remove, in this case Edit.NavigateTo and `remove`.

[image]

Comment: There is no shortcut assigned to Edit.NavigateTo in my configuration. Nothing to remove.

Comment: This does not fix the problem for me.  Holding ctrl still creates a hyperlink like action on a variable which still pops up the 'peek' window.

Comment: Sure thing - I'm not sure if I'm reading the question wrong on this post - However what did work for me I linked in the comments of the question.  If I misunderstood what this is fixing I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

An update for Productivity Power Tools + VS2017. Instead of having settings for this feature, a separate plugin gets installed. So after installing PPTs, you'll have a new extension called `Ctrl+Click Go To Definition`. Not sure why we need that tool considering it's baked into VS, but...

Anyway, Disabling that extension (plus the other things mentioned in other comments for VS and Resharper) fixed my ctrl+click woes.

Comment: @Ma'moun othman FWIW I rolled back your edit of `ctrl` because the label of the extension is _actually `Ctrl+Click` and I wasn't instructing the user to use the `CTRL` key.

Answer (score 0):

**To switch to the Visual C# keyboard mapping scheme**

- On the Tools menu, click Options.
- Expand Environment, and then click Keyboard.
- Select Visual C# 2005 from the Apply the following application
  keyboard mapping scheme drop-down list.

**or you can do**

Keyboard:  `CTRL + W`

**also plugin can be used**

[image]

[Keyboard Shortcut Exporter](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ce3b73c-2284-4b95-b61d-6de74aa8dfe6)
you can import/export keymapping file

Comment: Resetting the Keyboard Mapping to C# 2005 failed to stop the Ctrl+Click Navigation

Comment: I've VS2013 installed if you need, then I can provide you its exported key mapping file, you can import it to your VS2015 using plugin