# How to disable peek on go to definition

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In visual studio when i press F12 (go to definition) on any methods it open in a "peek" kind of window on the right side of the document tabs in fushia/pink like color on the dark theme. The problem is that 99% of the time i need to F12 into 2 or more methods but that window keep being replace by the latest. So i need to remember to click pin for every single time i press F12. I am wondering if i can disable this peek and make F12 open in a normal window like i opened the class.

I already disabled the preview class on the project treeview which open any class in the same "peek" tab.

I found some help but for VS2013 with powertool but VS2015 these tools are integrated and i didn't found the equivalent option menu.

My VS is up to date excluding the latest Azure update which i don't use.

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433905/can-you-turn-off-peek-definition-in-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Check the Visual Studio options:

- Disable "Control click shows definitions in Peek" option in:
  <kbd>Options</kbd>→<kbd>Productivity Power Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Other Extentions</kbd>.
- Disable "Allow new files to be opened in preview tab" in: <kbd>Options</kbd>→<kbd>Environment</kbd>→<kbd>Tabs and Windows</kbd>.
- Ensure you have <kbd>F12</kbd> key assigned to `Edit.GoToDefinition` per `Global`
  scope in: <kbd>Options</kbd>→<kbd>Environment</kbd>→<kbd>Keyboard</kbd>.

**UPDATE**: It works for Visual Studio 2017 as well.

Comment: Productivity power tools does not exist in VS2015. The second point did the job. i only had the find result checked in the sub list.

Comment: @Franck, PPT exist in VS2015 (at least for Enterprise ed.). I have such extention and this node in my `Options` tree.

Comment: @llya VS2015 Professional edition does not have this option. Gotta check the Community Edition at home see if this one has.

Comment: @Franck https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d

Comment: In VS2017, the first option exists at Options > Productivity Power Tools > General under "Control click options"

Answer (score 6):

In visual studio 2017, professional edition:

[image: In visual studio 2017, professional edition]

Answer (score 4):

For Visual Studio 2019, you can find the setting under <kbd>Options</kbd>-><kbd>Text Editor</kbd>-><kbd>General</kbd>-><kbd>Enable mouse click to perform Go to Definition</kbd>-><kbd>Open definition in peek view</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Following the accepted answer didn't work, I solved by unchecking:

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Pro

Answer (score 1):

I know its been a while. Anyways, here is how you can disable the Peek functionality when you do Ctrl+Click in Visual Studio 2015.

Go to Tools=>Options=>Productivity Power Tools=>Other Extensions and then simply uncheck the highlighted checkbox.

[image]