# How is possible to disable the nested preview/edit window in VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

There is feature in Visual Studio 2015 and/or ReSharper drives me crazy. I don't know what the name is. It comes up when I **Ctrl-click** on a method name. In older versions of VS it opened the file where the method/class implementation was. I want it back this feature.

I tried to search for it, but nothing so far. And it makes harder to find anything that I don't know name of this feature.

How can I disable it?

**It's duplicated. See Will's comments!**

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433905/can-you-turn-off-peek-definition-in-visual-studio-2013-and-up http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437340/how-to-disable-peek-on-go-to-definition try these and see if they work (they don't in 2017 so I can't verify)

Comment: @Will, this approach continues to work in VS2017. So, *SayusiAndo*, just use it to disable nested windows http://stackoverflow.com/a/34437772/5112433

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable peek on go to definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437340/how-to-disable-peek-on-go-to-definition)